# Is there always an injective map from a space in its dual space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Today our teacher said that dual spaces are "big" and told us that this is a consequence by Hahn-Banach's theorem. So I was wondering whether the dual space of a space is always "bigger" or equal compared with the space itself? I thought a good way to check the adjective "big" by mathematical methods is to ask whether there is an injective map in the dual space.

I am very interested in any comment on this.

Comment: If the linear space $V$ is finite dimensional, then its dual $V^{*}$ is finite dimensional as well, with same dimension.

Comment: Every vector space contains a basis. By considering a basis of $E$, you should be able to define an injective mapping $E\rightarrow E^*$.

Comment: sorry, but I am not just refering to the finite dimensional case

Comment: @Lipschitz the idea still works when the basis is infinite.

Comment: If one is talking Banach spaces, of course maps are expected to be continuous. Saying that $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ (which they are, as vector spaces) doesn't look like a very useful point of view.

Comment: Hahn and Banach are two different people....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about normed spaces and their continuous duals, this is not necessarily true.

Consider the sequence space $\ell_p$, where $1 < p < \infty$ and $p \neq 2$. Then the continuous dual $\ell_p^*$ is $\ell_q$, where $1/p + 1/q = 1$. It is possible to prove that $\ell_p$ does not embed into $\ell_q$ as a Banach space if $p \neq q$. In fact, even more is true. It is a theorem that $\ell_p$ and $\ell_q$ are *totally incomparable*: if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$, then $X$ does not embed into $\ell_q$ as a normed space (similarly for infinite-dimensional subspaces of $\ell_q$). This is corollary 2.1.6 in *Topics in Banach Space Theory* by Albiac and Kalton.

For vector spaces in general, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i). If $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, then $V$ embeds into $V'$ as a vector space and the dimension of $V$ is strictly less than the dimension of $V'$ (as cardinalities). In the finite-dimensional case $V$ and $V'$ have the same dimension.

Comment: Don't you need some further constraints on $p$, like $p < 2$? If I choose $2 < p < \infty$, then $\ell^p$ does embed into its dual space by the Hoelder inequality, no?

Comment: @anonymous: Actually you don't. The thing is, while $\ell_p \subseteq \ell_q$ when $1 \leq q \leq p \leq \infty$, the norms we are using in $\ell_p$ and $\ell_q$ when $p \neq q$ are different. As normed spaces they are very different, as I mention in my answer.

Comment: I still don't see the problem, actually. Lipschitz only wants the map to be injective (I will assume also linear and bounded); he/she does not say anything about continuity of the inverse (on the range). So say we have such a map $T \colon \ell^p \to \ell^q$ with $p \ne q$, then $T \colon \ell^p \to \operatorname{ran}(T)$ is injective, surjective, and bounded. But since $\operatorname{ran}(T)$ will not generally be closed in $\ell^q$, we cannot conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism between $\ell^p$ and a subspace of $\ell^q$, so that Corollary 2.1.6 does not apply, right?

Comment: @anonymous: $T$ is not an isometry.

Comment: Well, yes, but I never claimed it was (nor did @Lipschitz require it to be one).

Comment: Okay, but the inverse is not continuous. Because the inclusion $\ell_p \subseteq \ell_q$ is strict when $q < p$

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and give an answer to the question

> In what sense is the dual space of a normed space *larger* than the original space?

Smallness is not easily phrased for such a thing as an infinite-dimensional normed space. Cardinality certainly doesn't seem to help much (more on that later). One sense in which a space can be small is given by *separability* (Recall that any subspace of a separable (normed!) space is again separable).

If $X$ is a normed space and $X'$ is its dual, then one can prove the following.

- If $X$ is not separable, then neither is $X'$
- If $X$ is separable, then $X'$ need not be.

The spaces $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$ are examples for the second statement.

Another reason to view the transition to the dual as an enlargement is the fact that any normed space can be embedded in a very nice manner into its bidual.

Let's consider the spaces from earlier again. Since we actually have that $\ell^1$ is the dual of $c_0$, i.e. the space of sequences that converge to zero, $\ell^\infty$ is the bidual of $c_0$. Now, one can prove that $c_0$ can be viewed as the space $C(\alpha \mathbb N)$, i.e. the space of continuous functions on the Alexandroff (or 1-point)-compactification of $\mathbb N$. One can also prove that $\ell^\infty$ can be viewed as $C(\beta \mathbb N)$, i.e. the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb N$.

And that's where cardinality comes into play again. The set $\beta N$ has the cardinality $2^{2^{\mathbb N}}$, whereas $\alpha N$ still has cardinality $\mathbb N$. So in that sense, it's quite the leap from $C(\alpha \mathbb N)$ to $C(\beta \mathbb)$.